# Using ampersand symbols (&) instead of the word "and" for bibliography style apa

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

My supervisor just came with an idea to use the ampersand in citations and bibliography, so e.g.

```
Smith and Watson (1992)
```

should become

```
Smith & Watson (1992)
```

How can I make it work with bibtex and bibliography style apa?

Comment: Tell your advisor that book authors are not a firm. :)

Comment: Do you want the ampersand to appear only in the text citations or in the bibliography as well?

Comment: @Gonzalo, I would like it to appear everywhere consistently. However, if it is considerably easier to get it in citations only than I can start with that.

Comment: i know this post is a year old, but FYI this is **not** apa style. In-text references to authors should spell out the word "and". Ampersands are used only for the bibliography and parenthetical citations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a copy of `apa.bst`. (In a current TeX Live distribution it is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/apa.bst`
). Call it `myapa.bst` or something appropriate, and save it in your local texmf folder: `<path to local texmf>/bibtex/bst`.

Edit the function `{format.names}`

Change line 250

```
 { " and " * t * }
```

to

```
 { " \& " * t * }
```

Edit the function `{format.lab.names}`

Change line 876

```
{ " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

to

```
{ " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

Now use `\bibliographystyle{myapa}` in your document.

The current version of the APA style uses "&" in the bibliography, but not in the citations, I think.  So if you really need to conform, you should change only the `format.names` function, not the `format.lab.names`.

Alternatively, switch to using [`biblatex-apa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa), and redefine the `\finalnamedelim` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{<your-bib-file>}
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
   \addspace\&\space}
\begin{document}

...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\finalnamedelim` is not required if you don't change in-text citation "and"; the bibliography entries will automatically use "&".

Comment: It would be better to say: `renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addthinspace\&\addthinspace}`. This works only for the last name. To influence the other names you nee `\multinamedelim`.

Comment: @Marco Thanks, I'll fix that.  There shouldn't be any need to change `\multinamedelim`, which is usually a punctuation mark rather than 'and'.

Comment: You are right. `\multinamedelim` is normally a comma.

Comment: I get the error `Package biblatex Error: Style 'apa' not found.` if I try the second method. Can I put the modified sty file somewhere locally in the first method?

Comment: You need to install the `biblatex-apa` package, if it's not installed. For the first method, you can put the modified `.bst` file in the same directory as your `.tex` file and it should be found. (I assume that's what you mean by locally, since that's the only thing more local than your local texmf directory.)